# Get the host address programmatically in webnoir

Tags: clojure, noir

I'm developing a Clojure `webnoir` app and I need to construct a callback url (for Twitter oauth) that is different in dev-mode than it is in production mode. In dev-mode it needs to be  `localhost:8080/smth` and on production (heroku) obviously something else like `http://smooth-lightning-xxxx.herokuapp.com/smth`. How do I get the `localhost:8080` part programmatically in a `defpage`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end I solved it using this, inside a defpage, with `noir.request` required as `request`:

```
((:headers (request/ring-request)) "host")
```

Answer (score 4):

I haven't tried it, but I think this should work

```
(ns your-namespace
  (:require noir.request))
```

and then in defpage:

```
(let [server-name (:server-name (noir.request/ring-request))]
    ...)
```

You can also looke at [noir middleware](http://www.webnoir.org/tutorials/middleware) if you need to tweak requests and responses a lot.